# Area under a parabola revisited

Tags: python, sage

I was unable to go from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467771/function-calculate-area-of-region-under-parabola) because I was not a member of the website so I was unable to comment on it when I returned.
Here is my question:

To find the area of a region bounded by the graph y=x^2 and the x-axis on the interval [a,b] we can approximate the region by drawing a number of "thin" rectangles and taking the sum of their areas. Let us divide [a,b] into n smaller intervals of the same widght h=b-1/n. On each interval there is a rectangle with the height y=r where r is the middle of that small interval on the x-axis. The area of that rectangle is hy. Write a Python function that takes a,b, and n as parameters and returns the approximate area of the region under the parabola y=x^2 using the above method. If you could please explain as to why your program works that would be helpful.

Thanks to helpful members, I found the following program(please edit the program for i am unable/ don't know how to

```
def parabola(x):
    y = x*x
    return y

def approx_area(fn, a, b, n):
    """
    Approximate the area under fn in the interval [a,b]
    by adding the area of n rectangular slices.
    """

    a = float(a)
    b = float(b)
    area = 0.0
    for slice in range(n):
        left = a + (b-a)*slice/n
        right = a + (b-a)*(slice+1)/n
        mid = (left + right)*0.5
        height = fn(mid)
        width = right - left
        area += height * width

    return area

    print "Area is", approx_area(parabola, -1.0, 1.0, 500)
```

However, I would need to place this under one entire function.  Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Are we allowed to use calculus to come up with an analytical formula for the area underneath the parabola? It'll be quicker and more accurate.

Comment: @Ronnie, to enter code make sure there's a blank line before it and start each line with at least four spaces (more to get real indenting).

Comment: well i would have to use the method described in the question

Comment: It is the first time I see the phyton code. It looks like a loosely-typed language. Anyway, the function f(x)=x*x in question is hard-coded. Why don't you set it on the fly?

Comment: The right solution to *"can't edit the previous instance"* problem here is *not* to repost, but to contact the team and ask to have your current identity hooked up with the previous one. I'm going to flag this for moderator attention and maybe they can both deal with that and decide if a merge is in order.

Comment: ... keeping in mind that "found" means "was given it as an answer the second-previous time I posted this question (and have since screwed up the indentation)", of course.

Comment: @Ronnie: I merged your two accounts, so you can go back and comment and edit any of your old questions.

Comment: The integral of f(x) | [a,b] is the area under the parabola. This is an elementary numerical method for when the integral cannot be determined analytically. With lim(n->+infinite) it becomes the integral.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, by changing the function to `y = x` and trying some known input values, I conclude that it works fine:

```
0 .. 1 =>  0.5
0 .. 2 =>  2.0
1 .. 2 =>  1.5
0 .. 9 => 40.5
```

If you want it all in one function, just get rid of `parabola()`, remove the first parameter from the `approx_area()` function (and call), then change:

```
height = fn(mid)
```

to:

```
height = mid * mid
```

as in:

```
def approx_area(a, b, n):
    """
    Approximate the area under fn in the interval [a,b]
    by adding the area of n rectangular slices.
    """

    a = float(a)
    b = float(b)
    area = 0.0
    for slice in range(n):
        left = a + (b-a)*slice/n
        right = a + (b-a)*(slice+1)/n
        mid = (left + right)*0.5
        height = mid * mid
        width = right - left
        area += height * width

    return area

print "Area is", approx_area(-1, 1, 500)
```

Note that I wouldn't normally give this much explicit help for homework but, since you've done the bulk of the work yourself, it's only a small nudge to push you across the line.

I *would* warn you against handing in this code as-is since a simple web search will easily find it here and your grades may suffer for that.

Examine it, understand how it works thoroughly, then try to re-code it yourself without looking at this source. That will assist you far more in your career than just blind copying, trust me.

---

And just so you understand the theory behind this method, consider the slice of the function `y = x`:

```
7   .
6  /|
5 / |
  | |
  | |
  | |
  | |
  | |
0 +-+
  567
```

The midpoint y co-ordinate (and also the height) of the top is `(5 + 7) / 2`, or `6`, and the width is `2` so the area is `12`.

Now this is in fact the *actual* area but that's only because of the formula we're using. For a non-linear formula, there will be inaccuracies because of the nature of the "line" at the top. Specifically, in your case, a parabola is curved.

But these inaccuracies get less and less and you use thinner and thinner slices since any line tends towards a straight line (linear) as you shorten it. For the case above, if you divided that into two slices, the areas would be `5.5 x 1` and `6.5 x 1` for a total of `12`. If you line weren't straight, the two-slice answer would be closer to reality than the one-slice answer.

For your parabola (but from `x = 0 .. 1` to make my life easier, just double everything for `x = -1 .. 1` since it's symmetrical around the y-axis), the worst case in a one-slice solution. In that case, the midpoint is at `x = 0.5, y = 0.25` and, when you multiply that `y` by the width of `1`, you get an area of `0.25`.

With two slices (width = `0.5`), the midpoints are at:

```
   x       y    y x width
----  ------    ---------
0.25  0.0625      0.03125
0.75  0.5625      0.28125
                ---------
                  0.31250
```

So the area estimate there is `0.3125`.

With four slices (width = `0.25`), the midpoints are at:

```
    x         y   y x width
-----  --------  ----------
0.125  0.015625  0.00390625
0.375  0.140625  0.03515625
0.625  0.390625  0.09765625
0.875  0.765625  0.19140625
                 ----------
                 0.32812500
```

So the area estimate there is `0.328125`.

With eight slices (width = `0.125`), the midpoints are at:

```
     x           y    y x width
------  ----------  -----------
0.0625  0.00390625  0.000488281
0.1875  0.03515625  0.004394531
0.3125  0.09765625  0.012207031
0.4375  0.19140625  0.023925781
0.5625  0.31640625  0.039550781
0.6875  0.47265625  0.059082031
0.8125  0.66015625  0.082519531
0.9375  0.87890625  0.109863281
                    -----------
                    0.332031248
```

So the area estimate there is `0.332031248`.

As you can see, this is becoming closer and closer to the actual area of `1/3` (I know this since I know calculus, see below).

Hopefully, that will assist you in understanding the code you have.

---

If you *really* want to know how this works, you need to look into calculus, specifically integration and differentiation. These methods can take a formula and give you another formula for calculating the slope of a line and the area under the line.

But, unless you're going to be using it a lot and need real (mathematical) accuracy, you can probably just use the approximation methods you're learning about.

Comment: If you don't mind can you explain to me how the slice operator works, because i an unable to pick out the right words to explain it

Comment: @Ronnie, I've updated the answer to show how the slicing works. Just be careful with terminology since Python actually has a slice "operator" for getting slices of arrays (like `name[7:3]`).

Answer (score 1):

There is also a good visualization of this at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Formal_definitions

We look at the section of the parabola between a and b, and we divide it into a set of vertical rectangular slices such that the top-center of each rectangle is exactly on the parabola.

This leaves one corner of each rectangle "hanging over" the parabola, and the other too low, leaving unfilled space; so the area under the parabola is equal to the area of the rectangle, plus a bit, minus a bit. But how do we compare the bits? Is the area of the rectangle a bit too much, or not quite enough?

[image]

If we draw a line tangent to the parabola at the top-center of the rectangle, we can "cut off" the overlapping bit, flip it over, and add it to the other side; note that this does not change the total area of the rectangle (now a trapezoid).

[image] [image]

We can now see that there is a little bit of space left on either side under the parabola, so the area of the trapezoid is slightly less than the area under the parabola. We can now think of the trapezoid-tops as forming a bunch of straight-line segments (a "linear piecewise approximation") along the bottom of the parabola; and the area under the segments is almost the same as (but always slightly less than) the actual area we are seeking.

So how do we minimize the "slightly less than" amount, to make our calculated area more accurate? One way is to use curved approximation-pieces instead of straight lines; this leads into splines (Bezier curves, NURBS, etc). Another way is to use a larger number of shorter line-pieces, to "increase the resolution". Calculus takes this idea to the limit (pun intended), using an infinite number of infinitely short pieces.